# Get Twitter Feed of particular user

Tags: iphone, twitter

Hii i am trying to get twitter feed of particular user..

**My code:**

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                              URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jadoon88"]];

 NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:nil error:nil];

 NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
 NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                  options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
        NSLog(@"%@",publicTimeline);
```

**Error:**

```
 errors = (
            {
        code = 215;
        message = "Bad Authentication data";
    }
);
```

i have searched in this site but do not get proper answer. Do i need to add any library?? and if anyone know about nice tutorial than it will be great

Comment: Maybe your URL is error.

Comment: @nmh it may be do you know which exact url i have to use?

Comment: do u configured any other twitter account in your device?

Comment: @manujmv yes. can you tell me parameter screen_name is used for what??